# rails 4 model.joins using foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two tables in my database. One is called Protein and the other is called searchnames. Searchnames contains a column called protein_id which links back to proteins. I want to search through searchnames and produces a collect of Protein objects (so a ActiveRecord::Relation) based on what was collected from search names.

This is what I have so in my controller:

```
@protein = Protein.joins(:searchnames).where(searchnames: {"name LIKE ? " , "%#{params[:query]}%"})

@protein.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

This is what I have in my view:

```
<% if @protein.blank? %>
<p>There are not any proteins currently in the system. <%= @protein %> </p>
<% else %>
<p>These are the current proteins in our system</p>
<ul id="proteins">
<%= will_paginate @protein%>
<% @protein.each do |c| %>
   <li><%= link_to c.name, {:action => 'show', :id => c.id} %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag("index", method: "get") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:query, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:query) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Once I start up the server and go to http://localhost:3000/proteins/index, I get this problem:

```
   Started GET "/proteins/index" for ::1 at 2015-08-21 09:28:17 -0700
SyntaxError (C:/Users/Shams/Documents/Overall/topfind4/topfind4.1/app/controllers/proteins_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...(searchnames: {"name LIKE ? " , "%#{params[:query]}%"})
...                               ^
C:/Users/Shams/Documents/Overall/topfind4/topfind4.1/app/controllers/proteins_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
...KE ? " , "%#{params[:query]}%"})
...                               ^):
  app/controllers/proteins_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
  app/controllers/proteins_controller.rb:70: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Whats wrong with my syntax? Shouldn't the comma actually be there?

I am using Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.0.0 as well as mysql2.

Comment: Can't see anything immediately wrong with it. What is the actual problem?

Comment: Oh whoops, did not actually include the problem. Will edit and add it in now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions looks like a hash, but isn't one. When you want to use `LIKE` you need to use a different syntax:

```
@protein = Protein.joins(:searchnames).
                   where("searchnames.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:query]}%").
                   paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)
```

Comment: This worked! I guess I was reading the guides all wrong. As a learning point here, if this solution isn't a hash syntax, what kind of syntax is it?